# Loop to display parent categories in custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

I'm looking to display only the top level categories from a custom post type taxonomy I've created... product-category.

I'm hoping to pull the following data into a loop:

Category title (the_title())
Category description (the_archive_description())
Permalink (the_permalink())
Thumbnail (custom field... the_field(category_thumbnail))
Could somebody point me in the right direction please.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php
 $loop = new WP_Query();
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product-category', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
     foreach( wp_get_post_terms() as $term ) { ?>
         <div class="col-eq-height col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
             <div class="product">
                 <div id="thumbnail">
                     <?php the_field('product_category_thumbnail'); ?>
                 </div>
                 <div id="content">
                     <p id="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     <?php }
 endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: How is this question different from the one you posted yesterday? I‘m happy to amswer that one, but there‘s no need to post it multiple times.

Comment: Also, do we need your DIVs to know? Do they matter?